# LWC Datatable column value is not coming

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have a requirement where I need to show five columns (FirstName,LastName,Phone,Email,AdjustedPrice) of contact table in UI as a lightning datatable using LWC.
Out of five columns, four columns (FirstName,LastName,Phone,Email) are getting queried from contact object. But the fifth column (AdjustedPrice) is not coming from SOQL queries. I need to show some default value into it. This AdjustedPrice field not present in contact object.

Issue is: when I am fetching the current row, It is not considering the adjustedPrice column.

Below is the code snippet screenshot:

[image]

[image]

[image]

In the last screenshot, adjustedPrice is not coming in the row.

**HTML**:

```html
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Datatable with Row Actions" icon-name="standard:contact" > <br/>
       <div style="width: auto;">
           <template if:true={data}>

               <lightning-datatable data={data}
                                    columns={columns}
                                    key-field="id"
                                    hide-checkbox-column="true"
                                    onrowaction={handleRowActions}></lightning-datatable>
           </template>

       </div>

       <!-- Spinner -->
       <div if:true={showLoadingSpinner}>
           <lightning-spinner alternative-text="Loading" size="large"></lightning-spinner>
       </div>

       <!-- Detail view modal -->
       <template if:true={bShowModal}>
           <section role="dialog" tabindex="-1"
                   aria-labelledby="modal-heading-01"
                   aria-modal="true"
                   aria-describedby="modal-content-id-1"
                   class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open">
           <div class="slds-modal__container">
               <!-- modal header -->
               <header class="slds-modal__header">
                   <button class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-modal__close slds-button_icon-inverse" title="Close" onclick={closeModal}>
                       <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:close" alternative-text="close" variant="inverse" size="small" ></lightning-icon>
                   </button>
                   
                   <h2 id="modal-heading-01" class="slds-text-heading_medium slds-hyphenate" if:false={isEditForm}>Record Detail</h2>
                   <h2 id="modal-heading-02" class="slds-text-heading_medium slds-hyphenate" if:true={isEditForm}>Update Record Values</h2>
               </header>
               <!-- modal body -->
               <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium" id="modal-content-id-1" if:false={isEditForm}>
                   <dl class="slds-list_horizontal slds-wrap">
                       <dt class="slds-item_label slds-truncate" title="First Name">First Name:</dt>
                       <dd class="slds-item_detail slds-truncate">{record.FirstName}</dd>
                       <dt class="slds-item_label slds-truncate" title="LastName">Last Name:</dt>
                       <dd class="slds-item_detail slds-truncate">{record.LastName}</dd>
                       <dt class="slds-item_label slds-truncate" title="Phone">Phone :</dt>
                       <dd class="slds-item_detail slds-truncate"><lightning-formatted-phone value={record.Phone} ></lightning-formatted-phone></dd>
                       <dt class="slds-item_label slds-truncate" title="Email">Email :</dt>
                       <dd class="slds-item_detail slds-truncate"><lightning-formatted-email value={record.Email} ></lightning-formatted-email></dd>
                   </dl>
               </div>
               
               <!-- showing record edit form -->
               <div if:true={isEditForm} class="slds-theme_default">
                   <lightning-record-edit-form layout-type="Full" record-id={currentRecordId} object-api-name="Contact" onsubmit={handleSubmit} onsuccess={handleSuccess}>
                       <lightning-messages></lightning-messages>
                       <lightning-output-field field-name="AccountId"></lightning-output-field>
                       <lightning-input-field field-name="FirstName"></lightning-input-field>
                       <lightning-input-field field-name="LastName"></lightning-input-field>
                       <lightning-input-field field-name="Email"></lightning-input-field>
                       <lightning-input-field field-name="Phone"></lightning-input-field><br/>
                       
                       <div style="text-align:center;">
                           <lightning-button class="slds-m-top_small"
                                             variant="brand"
                                             type="submit"
                                             name="update"
                                             label="Update Record"></lightning-button>
                       </div>
                   </lightning-record-edit-form><br/>
                   <div></div>
               </div>

               <!-- modal footer start-->
               <footer class="slds-modal__footer" if:false={isEditForm}>
                   <lightning-button variant="brand"
                                     label="Close"
                                     title="Close"
                                     onclick={closeModal}></lightning-button>
               </footer>
           </div>
           </section>
           <div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop_open"></div>
          
       </template>
   </lightning-card>   
</template>
```

**JS**:

```js
import {LightningElement, track, wire} from 'lwc';

// importing apex class methods
import getContacts from '@salesforce/apex/LWCExampleController.getContacts';
import delSelectedCons from '@salesforce/apex/LWCExampleController.deleteContacts';

// importing to show toast notifictions
import {ShowToastEvent} from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';

// importing to refresh the apex if any record changes the datas
import {refreshApex} from '@salesforce/apex';

// row actions
const actions = [
    { label: 'Record Details', name: 'record_details'}, 
    { label: 'Edit', name: 'edit'}, 
    { label: 'Delete', name: 'delete'}
];

// datatable columns with row actions
const columns = [
    { label: 'FirstName', fieldName: 'FirstName' }, 
    { label: 'LastName', fieldName: 'LastName' },
    { label: 'Phone', fieldName: 'Phone', type: 'phone'}, 
    { label: 'Email', fieldName: 'Email', type: 'email' }, 
    { label: 'AdjustedPrice', fieldName: 'AdjustedPrice', type: 'text', default: 'AP'},
    {
        type: 'action',
        typeAttributes: {
            rowActions: actions,
            menuAlignment: 'right'
        }
    }
];

export default class DeleteRowsInDatatableLWC extends LightningElement { 
    // reactive variable
    @track data;
    @track columns = columns;
    @track record = [];
    @track bShowModal = false;
    @track currentRecordId;
    @track isEditForm = false;
    @track showLoadingSpinner = false;

    // non-reactive variables
    selectedRecords = [];
    refreshTable;
    error;

    // retrieving the data using wire service
    @wire(getContacts)
    contacts(result) {
        this.refreshTable = result;
        
        if (result.data) {
            
            this.data = result.data;
            //console.log('Data:' +JSON.stringify(data));
            this.error = undefined;

        } else if (result.error) {
            this.error = result.error;
            this.data = undefined;
        }
    }

    handleRowActions(event) {
        let actionName = event.detail.action.name;

        window.console.log('actionName ====> ' + actionName);

        let row = event.detail.row;

        window.console.log('row ====> ' + row);
        // eslint-disable-next-line default-case
        switch (actionName) {
            case 'record_details':
                this.viewCurrentRecord(row);
                break;
            case 'edit':
                this.editCurrentRecord(row);
                break;
            case 'delete':
                this.deleteCons(row);
                break;
        }
    }

    // view the current record details
    viewCurrentRecord(currentRow) {
        this.bShowModal = true;
        this.isEditForm = false;
        this.record = currentRow;
        console.log('record:' +JSON.stringify(currentRow));
        console.log('recordName:' +JSON.stringify(currentRow.name));
    }

    // closing modal box
    closeModal() {
        this.bShowModal = false;
    }


    editCurrentRecord(currentRow) {
        // open modal box
        this.bShowModal = true;
        this.isEditForm = true;

        // assign record id to the record edit form
        this.currentRecordId = currentRow.Id;
    }

    // handleing record edit form submit
    handleSubmit(event) {
        // prevending default type sumbit of record edit form
        event.preventDefault();

        // querying the record edit form and submiting fields to form
        this.template.querySelector('lightning-record-edit-form').submit(event.detail.fields);

        // closing modal
        this.bShowModal = false;

        // showing success message
        this.dispatchEvent(new ShowToastEvent({
            title: 'Success!!',
            message: event.detail.fields.FirstName + ' '+ event.detail.fields.LastName +' Contact updated Successfully!!.',
            variant: 'success'
        }),);

    }

    // refreshing the datatable after record edit form success
    handleSuccess() {
        return refreshApex(this.refreshTable);
    }

    deleteCons(currentRow) {
        let currentRecord = [];
        currentRecord.push(currentRow.Id);
        this.showLoadingSpinner = true;

        // calling apex class method to delete the selected contact
        delSelectedCons({lstConIds: currentRecord})
        .then(result => {
            window.console.log('result ====> ' + result);
            this.showLoadingSpinner = false;

            // showing success message
            this.dispatchEvent(new ShowToastEvent({
                title: 'Success!!',
                message: currentRow.FirstName + ' '+ currentRow.LastName +' Contact deleted.',
                variant: 'success'
            }),);

            // refreshing table data using refresh apex
             return refreshApex(this.refreshTable);

        })
        .catch(error => {
            window.console.log('Error ====> '+error);
            this.dispatchEvent(new ShowToastEvent({
                title: 'Error!!', 
                message: error.message, 
                variant: 'error'
            }),);
        });
    }

}
```

**LWCExampleController**.cls:

```java
public inherited sharing class LWCExampleController {
    
    @AuraEnabled(Cacheable = true)
    public static List<Contact> getContacts(){
        return [SELECT Id, FirstName,LastName, Phone, Email FROM Contact ORDER BY Name limit 10];
    }
    
    @AuraEnabled
    public static void deleteContacts(list<Id> lstConIds){
        try {
            list<Contact> lstConsToDelete = new list<Contact>();
            System.debug('lstConIds ====> '+lstConIds);
            for(Id idCon : lstConIds) {
                lstConsToDelete.add(new Contact(Id = idCon));
            }
            if(!lstConsToDelete.isEmpty()) {
                delete lstConsToDelete;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            throw new AuraHandledException(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE, please read [Why should I not upload images of code when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/8682068), then provide the code used to fetch contacts (where you set the list passed to the datatable). Once copy-pasted the code you could format it clicking `{}` or you could read how to enable [syntax highlighting for code](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting)

Comment: Are you asking how to incorporate a data value from a different object in this table?

Comment: Hi Keith, Thanks for responding. No , I am not asking that. My requirement is , this adjusted Price column is not coming from any object. This column has to be populated after some calculation. Like: One field is there called Price , it has a value $10. Now $2 discount has been provided. Ideally adjusted price should be showing $8.

Comment: But this column is not being considered when I am printing the row wise data.

Comment: Is this happening only for rows that don't have a value for that column ? If you plan on calculating values for this, you could use something like `currentRow.AdjustedPrice = some value` ?

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/documentation), there is no "default" attribute in column definition, so you can remove it and you can remove `type: 'text'` too since it's the default:

```js
const columns = [
    { label: 'FirstName', fieldName: 'FirstName' }, 
    { label: 'LastName', fieldName: 'LastName' },
    { label: 'Phone', fieldName: 'Phone', type: 'phone'}, 
    { label: 'Email', fieldName: 'Email', type: 'email' }, 
    { label: 'AdjustedPrice', fieldName: 'AdjustedPrice'},
    { label: 'Account Name', fieldName: 'AccountName' },
    {
        type: 'action',
        typeAttributes: {
            rowActions: actions,
            menuAlignment: 'right'
        }
    }
];
```

In order to add `AdjustedPrice` property to contacts record you must clone the records returned from the wired method because they are read only, so you could leverage [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method and [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).
The same goes if you have to show related fields, like `Account.Name`, since those are returned to child objects in the JSON, while the datatable needs a flat value related to the property specified in `fieldName` attribute:

```
@wire(getContacts)
contacts(result) {
    this.refreshTable = result;
    
    if (result.data) {
        // Adding the extra property
        this.data = result.data.map((contact) => {
            console.log('contact data:', {...contact});
            return {
                ...contact,
                AdjustedPrice: 'AP',
                AccountName: contact.AccountId.Name
            };
        });
        this.error = undefined;

    } else if (result.error) {
        this.error = result.error;
        this.data = undefined;
    }
}
```

This way the objects passed to the datatable will hold the `AdjustedPrice` property and the component will be able to show `AP` in that column.

Comment: It is working fine now. But when I am trying to get the Account related fields which is associated to the contact , like , account.name and account.fax , I am not able to render and fetch that in lightning datatable using map() method.

Comment: @Dips I updated the answer explaining how to show `Account.Name`, you have to apply the same logic for other related fields, please see column definition and wired method. You could use a console.log to know if it's `contact.AccountId.Name` or `contact.Account.Name`